# unable to generate HTML report using Webpack-bundle-analyser

Tags: javascript, webpack, command-line-interface

I'm trying to extract an HTML report separately using the following command:          **webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -r reports/analyzer/report.html**   where reports/analyzer would be the path name where the report.html should be generated. I tried using --report as well, but to no avail. On running the command, the report opens successfully on http://127.0.0.1:8888/ but a separate html file isn't getting generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have the permissions to the path you provide? What happens if you just enter `webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -r` ?

(by the way, -r is the [short version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) of --report, they are basicly the same command)

**Update**: you need to set the staic mode as well to make it work it seems:

```
webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -m static -r reports/analyzer/report.html
```

Comment: on entering **webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -r** I get an error for missing argument, because giving a file name after -r is mandatory. About the permissions for provided path, I'm not sure what kind of permissions you are implying here. The command **webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -r reports/analyzer/report.html** should create the directory reports/analyzer automatically right if it isn't already present?

Comment: what does webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json -m static -r reports/analyzer/report.html do?

Comment: that did it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer with that for other users to find: would you please so kind and accept it as the answer for your question?

Comment: I mean marking the answer with a green tick for being the "accepted" one for your question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png